# ORM: where to specify database constraints if db schema is maintained manually

Tags: hibernate, data-binding, orm, constraints

I see 3 variants:

1. specify db constraints in schema (*.sql) file
2. specify db constraints in ORM stuff(with xml/annotations/whatever)
3. use mix of 1) and 2)

Is there any Best Practice for this topic?
Particularly, I'm interested in Hibernate world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only constraints that are applied are the constraints that are in the database. Specifying constraints in Hibernate annotations is only useful if you're using the hibernate tools to generate the database SQL schema from the Java source code. In the end, it always ends up being in the SQL.

So if you maintain the schema manually and don't generate it from the Java annotations, using annotations to specify them is useless (except for documentation purposes).

Comment: Yep, you are right, I've just checked it. I thought Hibernate is checking (his) constraints before sending query to db - but it's not so. Thank you!

Comment: On the topic - if you would like business logic constraints as an addition to the DB constraints you can use Bean Validation. It will be executed in the pre-update, pre-remove and pre-persist phases.

Answer (score -1):

Though the JB Nizet's answer is valid still there is an exclusion - referential constraint [Foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key), "Referential actions" precisely. *Cascade* operations defined in (Hibernate) entity and foreign key referential actions defined in db schema works together.

Comment: Well, the things now look even more complicated. I just found that 'nullable' annotation parameter is checked by Hibernate (org.hibernate.engine.Nullability) during the persistence.